# javascript not working in firefox - icon bars unclickable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have written a webpage that works perfectly in Chrome but not in firefox. It is supposed to show icons on buttons, that are clickable and paste content onto a div.

Here is the sepcific part that doesnt work:

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-bar" id="iD-icon-bar">
        <button id="home" class="activeIcon" style="margin-left: 25%"><i id="homeIcon" class="fa fa-home" style="color: green;"></i></button> 
        <button id="search" ><i id="searchIcon" class="fa fa-search" style="color: green;"></i></button> 
        <button id="contact" ><i id="contactIcon" class="fa fa-envelope" style="color: green;"></i></button> 
        <button id="globe" ><i id="globeIcon" class="fa fa-globe" style="color: green;"></i></button>
      <div id="iconBar">
        <div id="iconBarHome" style='font-family:  Raleway; text-align: center; font-size: 25px; margin: auto; width: 870px; background-color: #609b58'>
            <br><h3>Vertical Icons</h3>
            <br><h5>This is just some placeholder container, to show what you can do with vertical tabs.</h5>
            <br><h6 style='height: 50px;'>made by devdoweb.com</h6>
        </div>

    </div>
```

JavaScript:

$("#search").click(function(){

```
$("#iconBarHome").html("<br><h3>Search</h3>\n\
<br><h5>This is just some placeholder container,\n\
to show what you can do with vertical tabs.</h5>\n\
<br><h6 style='height: 50px;'>made by devdoweb.com</h6>"); 


var ids = ["home", "search","contact", "globe"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)   {
document.getElementById(ids[i]).className = "inactive";
$("#search").addClass("activeIcon");

}
```

});

$("#home").click(function(){

```
$("#iconBarHome").html("<br><h3>Vertical Icons</h3>\n\
<br><h5>This is just some placeholder container,\n\
to show what you can do with vertical tabs.</h5>\n\
<br><h6 style='height: 50px;'>made by devdoweb.com</h6>"); 


var ids = ["home", "search","contact", "globe"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)   {
document.getElementById(ids[i]).className = "inactive";
$("#home").addClass("activeIcon");

}
```

});

$("#contact").click(function(){

```
$("#iconBarHome").html("<br><h3>Contact</h3>\n\
<br><h5><a href='mailto:hoffmannma84@googlemail.com'>send me an email</a></h5>\n\
<br><h6 style='height: 50px;'>made by devdoweb.com</h6>"); 


var ids = ["home", "search","contact", "globe"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)   {
document.getElementById(ids[i]).className = "inactive";
$("#contact").addClass("activeIcon");

}
```

});

$("#globe").click(function(){

```
$("#iconBarHome").html("<br><h3>Weblinks</h3>\n\
<br><h5><a href='https://www.w3schools.com/' target='_blank'>Webdesign tutorials</a></h5>\n\
<br><h6 style='height: 50px;'>made by devdoweb.com</h6>"); 


var ids = ["home", "search","contact", "globe"];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)   {
document.getElementById(ids[i]).className = "inactive";
$("#globe").addClass("activeIcon");

}
```

});
the inner html is supposed to go to the div with the id divMainText, which works very nicely in chrome, but not at all in firefox. The buttons just aren't clickable.

I am pretty new to html, css and javascript and have no idea if i am doing something completely wrong or something. I am very willing to look into php(never did) if this could be a solution for these kind of problems.

The Website can be found [here](http://www.devdoweb.com)

If you scroll down to the vertical tabs, that is the section in question.

Comment: [Developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/) is the key. First of all correct the errors showed in console. Firefox show an error `Cannot set property 'className' of null` here `document.getElementById('divmain').className = "mainDiv";` probably there isn't an element with `id` `divmain`.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is very confused. Notice the following points:

1. You are using the jQuery library. So, why have you used pure
   javascript in your code?
2. In the `html` code, inside the `<button>` tag is an `<i>` tag that
   has a similar `id` with `<button>` tag. The `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element So, the value must be unique within the HTML document.
3. You have used the `event` in your javascript code. But it is undefine for function. HTML events are **things** that happen to HTML elements. When JavaScript is used in HTML pages, JavaScript can **react** on these events.
4. There is no element with the `divmain` ID among the elements. So, `getElementById()` Method can't return any element.
5. And many other errors...

```js
function setActive ( e ) {
    $('[id]').each(function(  ) {
        document.getElementById(this.id).className = "inactive"
    });

    var ident = e.target.id;

    document.getElementById( ident ).className += " activeIcon";

    switch( ident ) {
        case 'home':
            $( '#divMainText' ).html( '<br><h3>Vertical Icons</h3><br><h5>This is just some placeholder container, to show what you can do with vertical tabs.</h5><br><h6 style="height: 50px">made by devdoweb.com</h6>' );
            break;
        case 'search':
            $( '#divMainText' ).html( '<br><h3>Search Section</h3><br><h5>No search function yet.</h5><br><h6 style="height: 50px">made by devdoweb.com</h6>' );
            break;
        case 'contact':
            $( '#divMainText' ).html( '<br><h3>Contact</h3><br><h5><a href="mailto:hoffmannma84@googlemail.com">Send me an email</a></h5><br><h6 style="height: 50px">made by devdoweb.com</h6>' );
            break;
        case 'globe':
            $( '#divMainText' ).html( '<br><h3>Weblinks</h3><br><h5><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Webdesign tutorials</a></h5><br><h6 style="height: 50px">made by devdoweb.com</h6>' );
            break;
    }

    document.getElementById('divMainText').className = "textMain";
}
```

```css
.icon-bar {
    width: 870px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: #a1abba url("http://www.devdoweb.com/lake01.jpeg") 50% 0 no-repeat
}
.icon-bar button {
    float: left;
    width: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: black;
    font-size: 36px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(88, 132, 82, 0.5);
    outline: none
}
.icon-bar button:hover {
        background-color: #1f9b71
}
.activeIcon {
    background-color: rgba(88, 132, 82, 1);
    transform: translateY(4px)
}
.textMain {
    text-align: center;
    width: 870px;
    margin: auto;
    font:  normail 25px Raleway;
    background-color: #609b58
}
.inactive {
    background-color: #609b58
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon-bar">
    <button id="home" onclick="setActive(event)" class="activeIcon" style="margin-left: 25%"><i class="fa fa-home" style="color: green;"></i></button>
    <button id="search" onclick="setActive(event)"><i class="fa fa-search" style="color: green;"></i></button>
    <button id="contact" onclick="setActive(event)"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color: green;"></i></button>
    <button id="globe" onclick="setActive(event)"><i class="fa fa-globe" style="color: green;"></i></button>
</div>

<div class="textMain" id="divMainText">
    <br>
    <h3>Vertical Icons</h3>
    <br>
    <h5>This is just some placeholder container, to show what you can do with vertical tabs.</h5>
    <br>
    <h6 style="height: 50px">made by devdoweb.com</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: I rewrote the whole section like in the edit, taking to heart some of the things you said, but still it only works in google chrome.

Comment: Check the code snippet in Google Chrome. It working.

Comment: I rewrote it again. Its now working in both browsers